# Unexpected behavior of Double data type

Tags: java, types, double, primitive

This is a sample piece of code I am trying. I know that it is because of double precision/roundoff. But let me know exactly what is happening and how to overcome it.?

```
public class DoubleSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double price1 = 16.99;
        double price2 = 12.99;
        int multiplier =10000;

        double price1updated = price1 * multiplier;
        double price2updated = price2 * multiplier;

        System.out.println("price1 "+price1updated);
        System.out.println("price2 "+price2updated);
    }

}
```

The output is

```
price1 169899.99999999997
price2 129900.0
```

Comment: No one is going to go through the maths by hand - read [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

That's because a `double` represents a decimal number with radix two, and `10` is not a power of `2`. This means that for certain values, the `double` equivalent will differ.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

- Use a `BigDecimal`; or
- Round the result up to the number of digits *"repairing"* the double yourself.

You can use a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to solve this problem. In that case the code would read something like:

```
BigDecimal price1 = new BigDecimal("16.99");
BigDecimal price2 = new BigDecimal("12.99");
BigDecimal multiplier = new BigDecimal(10000);

BigDecimal price1updated = price1.multiply(multiplier);
BigDecimal price2updated = price2.multiply(multiplier);

System.out.println("price1 "+price1updated);
System.out.println("price2 "+price2updated);
```

Or, you can round off the errors, by rounding results off to for instance two significant digits. Now there is a tiny chance if you do this with large numbers, that the result will not be correct, (for instance if the `multiplier` is greater than 1G). In case you want to round off on two digits, the code reads:

```
double price1 = 16.99;
double price2 = 12.99;
int multiplier =10000;

double price1updated = Math.round(price1 * multiplier * 100.0d)*0.01d;
double price2updated = Math.round(price2 * multiplier * 100.0d)*0.01d;

System.out.println("price1 "+price1updated);
System.out.println("price2 "+price2updated);
```

There is however no guarantee this will always help and as already said, it is possible the result will be a few cents more or less (but only on large numbers, so the relative error is very small).